# How to add a preBuild dependency on a task in an external build script?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my main grade.build file I have the following:

```
...
preBuild.dependsOn 'copyConfigFile'

task copyConfigFile(type: Copy) {...}

apply from: 'dirLocation/other.gradle'

import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
android {...}
```

There is a task in other.grade which I tried add as another preBuild dependency but gradle says the task can't be found in project :app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradle.taskGraph.whenReady, here is an example:

```
task installDebug
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
   installDebug.dependsOn 'projectA:projectB:installDebugExecutable'
}
```

Comment: @potassium You should also upvote answers you find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers